# When to specify uint size?

Tags: solidity, gas

It seems that specifying something less than `uint256` counterintuitively increases gas costs (or at best makes them equal to uint256 with optimization).

And since the minimum write to storage is 32 bytes (256 bits), it doesn't seem like specifying `uint8` would necessarily save you gas either.

In what cases could one use `uint<256` to save on gas?

One possible example: in a struct, if you group/list 8 `uint32` variables together, would writing to those 256 bits (which presumably are stored consecutively in one word) be the same storage / gas cost as a single `uint256` in the struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition on the struct is correct. It's efficient to write multiple uint<256 into a struct because of struct tight packing. According to the [solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html),

> Structs and array data always start a new slot and occupy whole slots (but items inside a struct or array are packed tightly according to these rules).

Basically, it's efficient to use uint<256 inside of a struct (or an array). In these cases, you typically want use the smallest uint sizes you can get away with in order to keep the total struct size at or under 256bits.

I'm not sure if there are other examples where uint<256 is more efficient than uint, but I'm sure someone can think of something.